# Android push notification off: how does it work internally?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-push-notification

**When we disable push notifications at app level**:

1. Does the OS automatically unregister the app from GCM/FCM ? (i.e) Will the GCM/FCM stop sending messages to the client for that app.
2. Will the push event listener code block be executed (minus UI tray) even when  push is off at app level ?

Comment: "disable push notifications at app level" please clarify what this is. Do you mean silencing a notification channel?

Comment: I meant Settings > Apps & Notifications > Notifications > App Notifications > [Choose an app] > Toggle the On to Off

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Does the OS automatically unregister the app from GCM/FCM ? (i.e) Will the GCM/FCM stop sending messages to the client for that app.

Yes. The GCM/FCM server doesn't determine if the device has disabled notifications for the corresponding app. So long as the device was targeted for the message, GCM/FCM will deliver the message.

> 2. Will the push event listener code block be executed (minus UI tray) even when push is off at app level ?

FCM for Android works differently depending the message payload type you sent. However, depending on the device, usually when Notifications are disabled, regardless of notification type, it would be blocked by the OS.

For more infos:

- [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45720700/are-push-notifications-delivered-to-android-phones-after-its-disabled-in-setting)
- [Received message in Android App](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive)
- [Can Firebase console push notification if apps is closed](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/issues/41)